# Amiga OS theme for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: themes

I have been using computers since c/pm. My favorite though was the Amiga 3000, are there any themes for 14.04 that have the look and feel of Amiga OS? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Amiga%20OS&oq=Amiga%20OS) google search I found [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/daily-5-five-retro-desktop-themes) OMG Ubuntu page, and that has Amiga OS theme to [download](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/zAmi+like?content=71028).